# How to get text boxes to except text added through JavaScript (Twitch TV chat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, twitch

So, I am trying to write a simple command chat bot for Twitch.tv chat, but I cannot seem to be able to get it to actually submit the text I add. Although I can add text and "click" the send button with JavaScript, it will not actually submit it.

For example, I can use http://www.twitch.tv/example to test it. Apparently it is not good practice on Stack Overflow to link to sites, but I do not know what else to do. I cannot recreate the problem in JS Fiddle because I do not know exactly what the problem is.

I can get these elements to seemingly work by using the Chrome console:

```
//finding the textbox
var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("chat_text_input mousetrap ember-view ember-text-area")[0];
//then assign some text to it.
textbox.value = "Hello, World.";
```

This works fine and the text appears.

```
//to send it I should merely find a way to click the "send" button
var send = document.getElementsByClassName("button primary float-right send-chat-button")[0];
send.click();
```

Well, this does not really work. It only actually submits the text if I physically either type or use a character (like shift) inside the textbox, or physically click the button myself. So, from what I understand there is some sort of event that is triggered when I physically type and click. Unfortunately, I do not understand how to find/trigger this event through the console. This is what I want to do.

Preferably I would like to do this in pure JavaScript, but I believe it may be simpler in jQuery. If it absolutely has to be jQuery that's OK and I will just have to suck it up and learn.

As a side note, I was able to successfully use this (with the elements changed of course), for YouTube live streaming chat. However, several other websites' chat react similarly to Twitch. These include web skype.

Comment: paste your `send` part in `browser - console` and see whether `send` variable has some value!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao It does not. Just a "" :(

Comment: then the element isn't present in `DOM`.. Could you please try to replicate the issue in `jsfiddle`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Well, the element is there. It just does not have any value assigned to it? If you put the code into http://www.twitch.tv/example it will return "" for the value of send.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I now see that using specific sites is not good practice. However, the overall problem is finding something that I do not know of right now. So I don't believe I can implement it in JS fiddle unless I know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent the last few hours poking around Ember and Javascript to figure this out. I too was running into an issue where I had to either click into the chat area or the send button itself.

I thought I had a lead with a script made for Twitch Plays Pokemon which  would send preset messages into the chat.  It used Jquery to input the value into the textarea and click on the send button, but that no longer works as Twitch now uses Emberjs 2

I am not too familiar with the Ember framework, but it seems Twitch utilizes a Textarea component(in Ember terms), which associates some framework specific API to the Textarea HTML element.

Since the Twitch webapp is written with Ember, it would seem that using vanilla javascript to set the value of the textbox would not notify the property change to whatever observers are registered internally to Ember

The workaround would then be to change the value property via Ember internal methods.  Luckily poking around the views associated on the Textarea DOM element gives access to the set method.
http://www.ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.TextArea.html#method_set

Ember.view.views worked pre-Ember 2 but was deprecated and now requires lookup

```
App.__container__.lookup('-view-registry:main')[document.querySelector(".chat_text_input").id].set("value","test");
document.querySelector(".chat-interface__submit").click();
```